# How to reduce EMI susceptibility for board to board connectors?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, gpio, emc

I am planing to design an MCU based board. Although I don't need all the GPIO's, SPI's, PWM pins, etc. I like many of them to be connected a card edge connector or board-to-board connector. So, I can be flexible to use those pins when I needed in the future without re-designing the board.

For example that might be the connector; [image]

However, the idea having spare GPIO's on the connector sounds very handy to me, on the other hand, even I set them as an output and pull-down or pull-up programmatically, I feel like that unused (for the time being) wires connected to a connector will look like an antenna and susceptible to EMI accordingly.

I have read some EMI considerations related books and articles. But, I couldn't really find something related to my subject or I totally overlooked it.

**Important note that:** There is a big chance I will have to go for FCC/CE certification.

My chain of questions;

1. Am I right to worry about antenna behavior and susceptibility to EMI?
2. If so, is there way to get over that concern while still using that unused pins on the connector?
3. Or should I completely avoid from using those unused pins on the connector?

I appreciate your inputs from now.

Comment: Just ground the lines via a 0 ohm resistor or solder pad (where a blob of solder makes a short), then remove that to use the connection when needed.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Just don't try to get the best of both worlds and do both though (drive and connect to gnd) ;)

Comment: General EMI tip -- use as many ground pins as you can afford.  I like one ground for every three signals, but this isn't always practical.  Use grounds also to separate high speed/low speed/analog, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drive the lines as outputs. Don't leave them as floating inputs.

Comment: Thanks @DKNguyen. I do usually set them as output, no question on that. My concern is more about wires from mcu up to connector rather than thinking how digital/analog signals are going to behave. That copper lines will be floating like antenna. That's my concern/question.

Comment: @Sener In your mind, how are copper traces floating if you are driving it to a fixed potential? Also, antennas do not float so the thing you are worried about isn't actually the thing you need to worry about. I think you have some concepts or terminology muddled.

Comment: indeed, it is not clear yet. This is why I am asking.To me a wire hasn't been ended from one end and running e.g. 100 mm, means floating. Maybe word floating is not the best one. Even that wire fixed to ground from one end, the other end looks open like antenna. if you say, this is not important and there is nothing wrong with that, I am more than happy to hear that then.

Comment: @Sener That is open, not floating. Floating means it has no fixed voltage and can wander. This isn't an antenna but can scatter radio waves. Driving it on one end with low impedance stops this and helps load down any radio waves it does pick up. Of course, they aren't perfect conductors so transmission line effects can happen at sufficiently high frequencies but designing effective radio isn't something that happens by random chance when you've gone out of your way to make it crappy. Also note antennas aren't always open either. Closed loops can pick up radio waves too.

Comment: Thank you @DKNguyen, your inputs clear things out fair enough. And yes, antennas are not necessarily open but my instance is an open one. I guess, I'd better test earlier if that traces will effect functionality of the product during EMC test. I understand now better the radio waves will be loaded down due to fixed voltage.

Answer (score 1):

I've been brought in to fix numerous failed-the-EMI-test PCBs. Failure was often in the 400MHz range.

Cure was

(1) to stitch the various regions of GND much more securely (if no plane used), and

(2) use 1Kohm resistors in long PCB traces, which dampen any resonances.

Regarding the long traces: suppose there is a resonance at 400MHz. Why not insert series lossy elements. Such large values convert the trace into an RC
delay element, if the R is at the driven end.

If bi-directional, use 100 ohms.

Comment: Thanks @analogsystemsrf. I can understand stitching GND regions. However, would you please elaborate about using 1K resistors?

Comment: You might want to mention where along the trace to locate the 1Kohm resistors and that they are series resistors.